# A reliable reference for the statement every $k$-tree is uniquely $(k + 1)$-colorable

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-colorings

I see that every $k$-tree is uniquely $(k + 1)$-colorable in [Uniquely_colorable_graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniquely_colorable_graph).
Wikipedia does not cite any references, even though I know that its proof is not difficult by using mathematical induction.

Are there any suitable books to refer to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume there are many "reliable references", here is one: [Well-covered Graphs, Unique Colorability, and Covering Range](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/288063435.pdf), it's a 6-line proof at the bottom of page 4.

Comment: Thank you.  But  I still don't know how to cite it. What kind of article is it?

Comment: the "recommended citation" is at the bottom of the first page; it's a Ph.D. thesis, that's a valid source, isn't it?

Comment: Nice! Thank you again.